# Does it still necessary to pack textures inside a texture sheet after Unity3D released 2D sprite support?

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, texturepacker, texture-atlas

I'm developing a 2D game. Since Unity3D already has a "sprite editor" and runtime 2D sprite texture support, does it still necessary to pack some small textures inside a texture sheet? What's the advantage to do so?

Besides, what do you guys do when you need to manage lots of small textures? Using some third-party tools like Texture Packer, or just drag all of them inside Unity and let Unity manage them?

Comment: The Sprite Editor is in fact a texture atlas (sprite sheet) editor. External texture packing tools are no longer needed to benefit from atlases, though they may offer some additional functionality.